# AVAudioPlayer could not stop playing music in iOS 7.1.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, avaudioplayer, ios7.1

AVAudioPlayer starts playing music when a local notification is shown to user. After clicking the notification and app runs in foreground I could not stop the music only in iOS 7.1.2. But I can stop it in iOS 8+.

Has anyone heard any iOS 7.1.2 bug about this issue reported by Apple?

I use the same instance that I start playing the music.

// start playing the music

```
[self.player prepareToPlay];
```

// Stop playing the music

```
[self.player stop];
[self.player setCurrentTime:0.0f];
```

Comment: have you check this : http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Playing_Audio_on_iOS_7_using_AVAudioPlayer

Comment: Yes. Also whatsapp has the same problem in ios 7.1.2. When an incoming call in app state backgorund, click local notification and answer the call. Ringing continues

Answer (score 0):

For playing use:

```
[self.player prepareToPlay];
```

For pausing/stopping use:

```
if (self.theAudio.playing) {
  [self.theAudio pause];
}

[self.theAudio stop];
self.theAudio.currentTime = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it didn't work (audio could not stop) for iOS 7.1.2 and the prepareToPlay is called when local notification presents in app state background. I have tested Whatsapp in ios 7.1.2 too and it has the same problem. So I think there is a bug in iOS 7.1.2, maybe someone has faced the same problem as me.

Comment: Also when ringing I killed the app but the sound still continues :)